# Rails / Cancan - load resources through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have these models:

```
Company 
  has_many :users
  has_many :accounts

User
  belongs_to :company

Account
  belongs_to :company
```

Users should have access to certain resources through their company, and I'd like to implicitly load those with Cancan:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  load_resource # Cancan doesn't know how to load through the user's company
```

I can obviously do this explicitly:

```
class AccountsController
  def index
    @accounts = current_user.company.accounts
  end
```

But this seems like unnecessary code and I suspect there's already a pattern for this.

I see that Cancan has the ability to define a `through` on the current user:

```
class AccountsController
  load_resource through: :current_user
```

But that will call `current_user.accounts` - that's invalid because accounts belong to companies, not to users. I could defer the `accounts` call from User to Company, but that seems like a hack.

I also tried passing in a string:

```
class AccountsController
  load_resource through: 'current_user.company'
```

And that gave me `'@current_user.company' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

I did some Googling but couldn't find it. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class AccountsController
  load_resource :company, through: :current_user, singleton: true
  load_resource through: :company
end
```

In your example, I believe you already have this in `@accounts = current_user.company.accounts`. Using cancan's `load_resource` to load the company, then the account should result in a similar set of queries.

Comment: That's it! I knew I was just missing something fundamental

Comment: @kid_drew thanks for the edit. Looking at the cancan docs that looks like the right way to do it.